# How to declare a type for an array with interface(s)?

Tags: typescript, types, interface

```
this.bestMatch = listOfFoundedMatches[userWithTheHighestRank];
```

The return of `this.bestMatch` would be:

[image]

For now I am using `private bestMatch;` but I would like to define a type declaration. Instead of `any` I could use an interface. I have tried it with:

```
export interface Imatch {
  email: string;
  first_name: string;
  last_name: string;
  gender: string;
  phone: number;
}

export interface Irank {
  absolute: string;
  relative: number;
}
```

Do I really need 2 interfaces or could it be only 1?

Since I have `0` or `rank` and `data` before the interface(s), I don't know how I could declare a type. How would you guys do it?

Comment: I think you shouldn't worry about number of interfaces.  I'd probably create a third interface: `interface BestMatch { data: Array<Imatch>, rank: Irank }`? and then your class would have a property like `class Foo { bestMatch: BestMatch; }`

Comment: @jcalz this is exactly the answer that I wanted. Thank you!!